# Using @SuperBuilder, how can I have a subclass also inherit its parent superclass properties?

Tags: java, inheritance, lombok, builder

Given this structure;

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class CHouse {
    String address;

    String description;

    CParent parent;

}

@Data
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class CChild extends CParent{
    protected String childId;
}

@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class CParent {
    protected Integer parentId;
}
```

How can I achieve the following?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        CParent child = CChild
            .builder()
            .parentId(123)
            .childId("789")
            .build();

        CHouse house = CHouse
            .builder()
            .address("address")
            .description("description")
            .parent(child)
            .build();
    }
}
```

I would expect for child to be an object with the following :

```
CChild(childId=789, parentId=123)
```

And similarly for the house object to be:

```
CHouse(address=address, description=description, parent=CChild(childId=789, parentId=123))
```

However, it appears that it is not picking up the parentId attribute. How can I fix this?

Comment: The issue is that you need to add the @SuperBuilder annotation to the CChild class in order for it to inherit its parent's properties. With that annotation in place, the code should work as expected.

Comment: I did add it. All 3 classes have the @SuperBuilder annotation added, although I believe the one on the CHouse class is unnecessary.

Comment: What makes you say that parentId hasn't been picked up? How are you checking that?

Comment: It actually was picking it up but it needed the @ToString(callSuper=true) annotation. I was confused because when trying to access via dot notation, it wouldn't show the getter/setters for it.

Answer (score 0):

`parentId` was actually being picked up. I thought it was not since when I printed out the object it showed none of the derived class properties. By adding `@ToString(callSuper=True)` to the subclass fixed my problem.